# restassured - I can't pass one variable from one method to another

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to rest assured and Java, and I'm trying to get a variable from one method (or test case) to another, and I keep getting "null".

I've tried many different things but I just keep getting the error. Basically, what I want is to get "id" from test "getTweet" and pass it to test "deleteTweet". Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class twitterTesting {


    String consumerKey = consumer;
    String consumerSecret = secretConsumer;
    String accessToken = token;
    String accessSecret = secretToken;
    String tweetText = "Never give up!";
    String id;



    @Test
    public void createTweet() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses";
        given().
                auth().oauth(consumer, secretConsumer, token, secretToken).
                queryParam("status", tweetText).
                when().post("/update.json").
                then().assertThat().statusCode(200);



    }

   @Test
    public void getTweet() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses";
        Response res2 = given().
                        auth().oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessSecret).
                        queryParam("count", "1").
                        when().get("/home_timeline.json").
                        then().assertThat().statusCode(200).
                        and().extract().response();
        JsonPath jsonResponse = resources.rawToJson(res2);
        String text = jsonResponse.getString("text");
        id = jsonResponse.getString("id");
        System.out.println(id);
        //System.out.println("/destroy/" + (id.substring(1, id.length()-1) + ".json"));
        String textModified = text.substring(1, text.length()-1);
        System.out.println(textModified);
        System.out.println(tweetText);

        assert text.contains(tweetText); //true
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteTweet() {
        System.out.println("/destroy/" + id + ".json");

    }
}
```

I keep getting /destroy/null.json when it comes to sending id variable to the "deleteTweet" test case.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a test is run you get a new object, that's mostly by design; tests should be independent from each other. The advantage of that is that you can click a single (failing) test and run just that one test again, and, also, it means that you do not need to define in which order tests are run.

As a consequence, test classes should basically never have fields. Get rid of all of them.

To then 'fix' `deleteTweet`, make a (generally not marked with `@Test`!) method called probably getTweet (generally, test methods are called testDeleteTweet or some such, not deleteTweet), and call it from deleteTweet.

If you must go with the field stuff you can kind of do that; there is @BeforeTest, which you can put a method: That method will be executed for every test, every time, and this method could fill the 'id' field for you. But it does mean that method is invoked for every test method, even test methods that don't need it.